# Windows Terminal Autostart at Login

Tags: windows-10, autostart, windows-terminal

I configured Windows Terminal to start at login but I find it doesn't work and Task Manager keeps saying it is disabled after a reboot:

[image]

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you do to configure Windows Terminal to start at login in the first place? I see Windows Terminal in my startup list but I didn't do anything to configure it. I assume all I need to do is set the startOnUserLogin property as you said in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out.

There is a property "startOnUserLogin" that has to be set. Otherwise Windows Terminal will simply disable the autostart configuration set on the application.

Answer (score -1):

Hit Win+R and type shell:Startup. The startup folder will open. Now create a .bat file there with the code `wt`. It should start Windows Terminal at startup. And to enable it in task manager click on it and below click Enable.

Hope that helps

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I know how to configure it for autostart. I also know how to to click "enable". The problem is that it keeps reverting to "disabled" all the time.